# Kubernetes Fluentd multiline log

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a bunch of java container running on a Kubernetes cluster. The logs from these containers follow the common format of `date message, stacktrace`
These logs are separated and sent to Stackdriver as individual parts, even though they're the same log.

How can you configure GKE to include these stacktraces in the log message?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "These logs are separated and sent to Stackdriver as individual parts"? And how are they separated? Are they separated by date?

Comment: Like, instead of the message including the first part INFO classname Error from blah at classname:12323, and the stack trace are two different logs

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior, it is working as intended. If you would like to change that, there are a few approaches below on how to customize it:

1 - I found these two fluent plugins ([GCP-detect-exceptions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions) and [FT-detect-exceptions](https://github.com/Financial-Times/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions)) from the [fluent repo](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins) that will answer your question.

2 - You  could also use [structured logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging). To do so, you should also reinstall the logging agent. You could write the "date message" into the logs as a jsonPayload.

3 - Here is [another approach](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/#changing-fluentd-parameters) that would help you change the fluentd parameters to customize the log output. This approach mentions that you should create a new `ConfigMap` and then change `Daemonset` to point to it.